# Mysqli AES_DECRYPT

Tags: mysqli, aes

I wonder if any of you can help me with this.  I have no trouble encrypting a field and writing it to a database.  For example:

```
$query= mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO users (surname) VALUES    (AES_ENCRYPT('Blenkinsop','mypassword'))");
```

The problem comes when trying to get it out again:

```
$query =  mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT AES_DECRYPT(surname,'mypassword') FROM users WHERE userID = 1"); 

while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    [$row['surname']]; }

echo $row[0];
```

I have tried a number of variants, including echo $row['surname']

The error give is:  "Undefined index: surname in line...", and the line refers to the line:  [$row['surname']].

However, at the bottom of the error screen it says:

```
$row = array (size=1)
'AES_DECRYPT(surname,'mypassword')' => string 'Blenkinsop' (length=10)
```

Se the decryption is working; I just cannot find the right syntax to get it out.

If I just run the query without decryption it runs fine with no errors, and echos the still encrypted name:

```
$query =  mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT surname FROM users WHERE userID = 1");
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Steve Moss

Comment: Hi Ryan, Yes, certainly interested.  If you could let me have some details I'd be very grateful. Steve

Comment: Can't you just redefine the column and be done with it? `SELECT AES_DECRYPT(surname,'mypassword') AS decrypted_surname FROM...`

Comment: Hi Artjom B. , Your suggestion  was a very elegant and straightforward solution.  It worked perfectly.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score -1):

column type `surname` = varbinary (50)

```
$query =  mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT *, CAST(AES_DECRYPT(surname,'mypassword') AS CHAR(50)) surname FROM users WHERE userID = 1");
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Try to explain more clearly why this is an answer to the question.